# Как добавить несколько объектов в Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

Я из кода создаю несколько элементов в Grid:

```
List<Button> btn_arr = new List<Button> () {new Button{//Тут параметры кнопки}, .... };

for(int i = 0; i < btn_arr.Count; i++) {
    Grid.Children.Add(btn_arr[i]);
}
```

Как сделать так чтобы все элементы притягивались к верхнему краю, а также чтобы они отталкивались друг от друга.

Если просто к каждому элементу добавлять `VerticalAlignment="Top"`, то они сливаются в кашу, как этого избежать?

И еще дополнительный вопрос, если элементы достигли нижнего края, то на Grid создавался `ScrollBar` и все элементы перемещались.

Comment: Создайте StackPanel, добавьте в нее кнопки, и потом добавьте эту панель в Grid

Comment: @АлексейПотапов Действительно, спасибо, можно спросить, а как теперь эти элементы скролить?

Comment: Добавьте StackPanel в ScrollViewer, а уже вьювер в грид, я думаю есть более изящное решение, но и это рабочее, я сам не спец WPF https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/5.20.php

Comment: В WPF оооочень плохо использовать создания контролов через код. Для этого в нем есть XAML и привязки. Очень сильно советую вам научиться ими пользоваться!

Comment: То что вы делаете, это стандартная задача для `ItemsControl`

Comment: @АлексейПотапов Все помогло, спасибо!